# CURL POSTFIELDS to contain "&" character

Tags: php, curl, urlencode

I have working SMS sending over gateway using CURL method.
But If I include this character "&" in my message text area, it will send the message before this character only.

So how I could fix it to send messages including this character normally.

here is my code:

```
$from = "Gateway_username"; // SMS username
$token = "Gateway_password"; // SMS password
$option = $_REQUEST["option"];
$text = $_REQUEST["BulkSMS1__messageTextBox"];

if ($text == "") { } else {

    $url = "http://awaljawaly.awalservices.com.sa:8001/Send.aspx";
    $postfields = array ("REQUESTTYPE" => "SMSSubmitReq",
    "Username" => "$from", "Password" => "$token", "MOBILENO" => "$d_mobile", "MESSAGE" => "$text");

    if (!$curld = curl_init()) {
    echo "Could not initialize cURL session.";
    exit;
    }
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($curld);
    curl_close ($curld);
    preg_match("/(.*)/",$output, $out);
}
```

This is a sample message:

> Our Address: H&R Center.

Thanks in advance.

I have used this to fix my issue:

```
$text = str_replace('&', '%26', $_REQUEST["BulkSMS1__messageTextBox"]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this to fix my issue:

```
$text = str_replace('&', '%26', $_REQUEST["BulkSMS1__messageTextBox"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to encode the characters:

http://www.clockworksms.com/blog/the-gsm-character-set/

With this, try using:

```
utf8_encode()
```

The reason for this is that you're encoding for a mobile device, not a website, so using url encode will not work, compared to utf8 encode.

Comment: You are right, but still not fixed,
I have also tried to replace "&" character with "%26" but didn't work :(

Comment: http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/ETSI/GSM0338.TXT - Using this you could iterate through each character, and find if it's equal to the symbol in an array, and from there convert it to the right unicode  (second column)

Answer (score 1):

See urlencode() -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

```
<?php
$text = urlencode($_REQUEST["BulkSMS1__messageTextBox"]);
?>
```

Comment: I have already tested it before, and used rawurlencode too.
But they are not working.
@adam-sinclair